# Android color picker - updating color array

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a color picker for Android that looks like a minimalistic version of Gimp's. So, it has a hue slider and a rectangle with saturation/value variants of a color chosen in hue slider.

Question: what is the best way to create the rectangle?

Right now, I'm creating an 200x200 array of pixels, but it takes ~5sec to create and display rectangle with that array. And I need colors in rectangle to change whenever I change the value in hue slider...

Rectangle is bitmap, btw. Can I use color matrices on that and how? Any examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know about the color matrices, but do you really have to calculate the bitmap completely new when something changes? Maybe there's a fast way to just calculate some sort of delta?

Would you mind posting the code? Although I can't help you, I'd really like to see how the colors in the rect are calculated..

Comment: Color matrices are definitively the way to go! I just merged two things I found on net and the bitmap is now changing color in real time. I need some more time to brush up the code, but take a look at these two links:
- http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16463 (just comment out mPaint.setColorFilter(null);)
- http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000565.php

So the whole idea is to create a bmp with a paint object, and then to add a filter to that paint in the form of ColorMatrix.

Answer (score 8):

You can create the rectangle with saturation/value variants that change according to the selected hue, by drawing the rectangle with LinearGradients.

You can incorporate the code here: http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/ into your application. Seems that this is what you want.

Comment: yuku, your color picker looks great! Looking into using it for DigiClock widget, loving that it doesn't need intents and other apps to be installed, thanks a tonne!!!

Comment: I've added this one to DigiClock widget, and so far my users are really impressed. Thanks again yuku!!

Comment: looks very nice, I might use this :)

Answer (score 4):

OpenIntents has a very nice color picker you can use.  It can be installed as an independent app and launched with Intents.

- Code: http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/#svn/trunk/ColorPicker
- Screenshots/download: http://www.openintents.org/en/colorpicker
- Intent specification: http://www.openintents.org/en/node/670

Comment: All of the links are broken. http://www.openintents.org/action/org-openintents-action-pick-color/ is the closest to a color picker that is available on openintent.org.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to pre-create the rectangles on your developer PC for each slider position, embed them as resources, and then swap in the right one when the slider changes. This may make for a portly application, but it will be nice and quick.

I have not dealt with the 2D graphics API much, so I don't know if there are other possibilities (e.g., color matrices).

Answer (score 0):

Can this be applied to an image color picker as well?

Use case:

1. Select a particular pixel on an image.
2. The pixel selected generates a color on a rectangle shape.
3. Perhaps generating color codes for the pixel selected?