# Android Color Picker

Tags: java, android, colors

Does anyone know of a quick color picker widget that I could grab to use in my application?

I've seen one in a few different applications that have a wheel with colors, and that you tap in the center to select, but I'm not sure where to find it.

Any color picker would be fine though.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The wheel color picker that you are talking about is in the API Demos.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorPickerDialog.java

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a custom widget and not something built into the API.

Comment: That color picker has now been adapted into a standalone app that can be used with Intents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542806/android-color-picker-updating-color-array/2727284#2727284

Comment: Produces pretty nasty results when taken out of the 4.2 samples. :-(

Comment: why is the `ColorPickerDialog.java` moved to the `legacy` folder in the Android-18 sample code ?

Answer (score 23):

Created ColorPickerPreference to use in preferences.
Used above submitted color-picker-view
can find it here:
https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference

Also will share similar ColorPickerPreference with Rotary Picker (used it before)

Comment: Thanks for this - imo it's the perfect combination of ease-of-use and flexibility (i.e. optional alpha slider.) Works great for choosing some colors for a graph interface, since my code can utilize alpha values.

Comment: Making this work with HoloEverywhere wasn't a completely straight forward process, so I have a fork of this library that works with it: https://github.com/gsingh93/android-ColorPickerPreference

Comment: As someone new to Android Development - is there an installation guide somewhere? Do I just copy and paste these files into my project?

Answer (score 20):

This one from Yuku ( http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/ ) is really kewl. It's open source under Apache license, and is much nicer than the Android sample one. It's also a library project, so it's really simple to integrate. I've just added it last week to DigiClock widget, and so far my users are impressed!

Comment: I added an optional alpha slider to the Yuku picker: https://code.google.com/r/obsidian17-colorpickeralpha/source/browse

Comment: FYI this library has been migrated to github and uploaded to Maven:
https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna

Answer (score 4):

You can use CommonsWare's [cwac-colormixer](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer).

It's an android library now! :)

Comment: It has a dependency on CWAC-Parcel.jar, which unfortunately he does not provide.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: it's open source. look for it at his github repo.

Answer (score 3):

A rather advanced one from OI Flashlight is [here](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Flashlight/src/org/openintents/widget).