# How to define AlertDialog.Builder inside a newView/bindView

Tags: android

I have a ListView and I'm using SimpleCursorAdapter to populate the content, and newView & bindView to get the View.

I want to enable that everytime the button on the row list is clicked, it loads an AlertDialog box.

Here's the code:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null) {
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, new String[] {
    BaseColumns._ID, Database.Project.C_PRICE, Database.Project.C_KEYWORD,
    Database.Project.C_SHORTCODE}, null, null, null);

if (cursor == null) {
finish();
} else {
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);                                             
alertbox.setTitle("SMS");
```

I always get an error on this line: `AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

It says: `The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined`

how am I able to do that?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/7156762/964741 , if u not understand let me know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `this` to create the `AlertDialog.Builder` which is wrong use `Activity_name.this`. You are applying the button's listener's reference to create the AlertDialog.Builder rather you should have the reference of the Activity.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_name.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
         AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
     }
}
```