# Edit to select colors : Android

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, edit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Color Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442407/android-color-picker)

I would like to know if exist some type of edit in android to select a color.

Like Photoshop have when you select the color of the pencil, opens a window with a grid with all tones of colors, then the user can select some color and the edit return the hex of this color to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find one here, I think this could be helpfull for you.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorPickerDialog.html