# Android: advanced ColorPickerDialog

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm looking for an advanced Android color picker dialog. The standard color picker from the API Demos and examples from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442407/android-color-picker) aren't quite acceptable to me. I'd like it to look like this: [this image](http://cdn6.droidmill.com/media/market-media/com.siyusong.android.color.picker_0.png). Are there any open source color pickers that look like that?

UPDATE: My primary goal is to make the Color Picker easy to use: it'd be great if the user only needs to click once to pick any color, and all possible colors are represented. The Color Pickers from the examples I've mentioned require two clicks to pick a color and are too complicated for the average user.

Answer (score 7):

This one looks pretty close to what you want, and is FOSS:
https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker

[image]

Comment: Where is the support for black & white colors?  I don't see them here.

Comment: seems to be bad color picker, how would you suppose to see the color while you will have your finger or thumb on it.

Answer (score 6):

how about [this](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/colorpickerpreference/) solution ?

look at the screenshot:

[image]

source code [here](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference) .

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I haven't read the code of what i've posted about, so i have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Android Color Picker](http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/)?
If you need to show the RGB-Code of the currently selected color, just modify the dialog by adding an TextView and adding an update to it in the ColorChangeListener (or whatever it's called)

Or take a look at the color-picker dialog of CyanogenMod
[image: Color-picker Dialog of CyanogenMod]

Here a link to the source: [CyanogenMod color-picker on GitHub](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/527f17f73f76feee76f50d022c7b7629d288e312/src/com/android/settings/notificationlight/ColorPickerView.java)

Comment: Wrong link, the CyanogenMod color picker is not same as shown in above screenshot.