# Android Color Selector

Tags: android, color-picker

I'm looking for a way for my users to select the color of an image. I've already written code to change the image to colors that I have hard coded in as options, but I'd like for my user to be able to choose ANY color if they aren't satisfied with my pre-selected choices.

I know I've seen color selectors in apps before, but there doesn't seem to be one built into the Android SDK, or if there is I'm missing it. Can someone point me in the right direction to get a color picker that I can use for my app?

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442407/android-color-picker and thousands of other results that Google returns.

Comment: Except that the code in those examples doesn't even compile, let alone work, and the links in the other answers are dead ends. I tried Googling, and searching here, and came up with no useful answers.

Comment: For the record, I ended up finding this: http://color-picker-view.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ it works well on both tablets and phones, and it's big enough that you can actually see it and use it properly.