# Where are the API Demos, particularly Demo Color Picker, in Android SDK 24

Tags: android

I am trying to use a color picker in Android Studio. There is no color picker in the palette box. However, from online [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442407/android-color-picker), there is a color picker in what has been dubbed as the API Demos.

```
Mac-mini-3:android-24 myuser$ pwd
/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-24
Mac-mini-3:android-24 myuser$ ls
android-stubs-src.jar   data            package.xml     source.properties
android.jar     framework.aidl      sdk.properties      templates
build.prop      optional        skins           uiautomator.jar
```

But where am I supposed to find the API Demos?

On the Android SDK Manager, I do not see "Samples" mentioned anywhere, as this [image: screenshot] shows.

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this answer looking for the old API demos sample, I got it running with Studio, despite some legacy code in the sample:

https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-api-demos-for-studio

Regarding The color picker from the old API demos app, it needs a bit of work for todays modern devices. But I sucked the code out of the API demos sample and it can be found here:

https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-color-picker-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It should be installed from the Android SDK Manager by checking the **Samples for SDK** option.

You can also download them directly from:

1. [android/platform/development/nougat-release/+/samples](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/nougat-release/samples/)
2. https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

I could not find any Color Picker from the list of samples though.

Comment: I understand your suggestion here. By downloading Samples for SDK in the SDK Manager, it should download files to the sdk download location on my disk. Unfortunately, when I launch the SDK Manager, the option you recommend does not appear anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried updating the SDK Tools and Platform Tools packages (then restarting the SDK Manager)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my repository for Android ApiDemos : https://github.com/av930/ApiDemos
please refer it.