# Color picker for Android returning value without "OK" button

Tags: android

I'm trying to create Android app to pick color and send it via Bluetooth to Raspberry.

Right now, I'm using this: https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna,
    but it works as a dialog window and return selected value when "OK" button is pressed.

I want my app to have a color picker in MainActivity without any dialog or pop up and return current value in "real time" when user is selecting new color.

i found this question: [Android color picker - updating color array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542806/android-color-picker-updating-color-array),
    but I'm new in Android apps and I need some example of code and step by step solution for newbie.

Thanks for help in advance.